# How to setup google maps direction service and distance matrix javascript api

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, web

I am working on a project to draw a route for a bus and show the total distance it will cover in a div within my html file. Am having issues with my javascript sources being imported into my html file containing google maps javascript api. Below is a screenshot of my problem.My errors from the javascript console are:

1. Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on
   this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
2. initMap is not a function.

I want to be able to see the map with the route details and path in one div and the distance and estimated time of arrival of bus to the destination.
Currently, when i move the 
between the top or bottom, i either get the map or get the distance calculations.
Your help will be highly appreciated...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "view_distance">
      <br>
      Basic example for using the Distance Matrix.<br><br>
      Origin: <input id="orig" type="text" style="width:35em"><br><br>
      Destination: <input id="dest" type="text" style="width:35em"><br><br>
      Distance: <input id="dist" type="text" style="width:35em">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB9SXvLdo1FnKd8lcuVtvQaSx1tqqE_NFA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center:  {lat: -15.408200, lng: 28.287201}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        DisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);


      }

      function DisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin:  {lat: -15.408200, lng: 28.287201},//Lusaka
          destination: {lat: -17.8419, lng: 25.8543},//Livingstone
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(-15.408200,28.287201),
        destination = {lat: -17.8419, lng: 25.8543},//Livingstone
        service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        },
        callback
    );

    function callback(response, status) {
        var orig = document.getElementById("orig"),
            dest = document.getElementById("dest"),
            dist = document.getElementById("dist");

        if(status=="OK") {
            orig.value = response.destinationAddresses[0];
            dest.value = response.originAddresses[0];
            //displays the distance
            dist.value = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + status);
        }
    }
    </script>
    <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB9SXvLdo1FnKd8lcuVtvQaSx1tqqE_NFA&callback=initMap">
    </script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>
          
                var start = {lat: -15.3875259, lng: 28.3228165};
                var end = {lat: -17.86263115, lng: 25.85589126};
                var stophere = {lat: -17.3426664, lng: 27.26371218};
          var stophere2 = {lat: -17.02884158, lng: 26.48808979};
          
                var waypts = [{location: stophere,stopover: true},{location: stophere2,stopover: true}];
       
                 function initMap()
              {
                  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
              {
                      zoom: 15,
                      center: start,
             mapTypeControl: true,
                      mapTypeId: 'satellite',
          rotateControl: true,
                      fullscreenControl: false

                   });
          
                 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                 calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        
           //Center control methods
           var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
                 var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
     
                 centerControlDiv.index = 1;
                 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(centerControlDiv);

        
           //infoWindows begin here
              var contentString = '<div id=\"content\">'+
                 '<div id=\"siteNotice\">'+
                 '</div>'+'<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\">'+'Tap other markers to see information<br/><br/>your STARTING POINT...'+'</h4>'+
                 '<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\" style=\"color:red;\">10</h4>'+
                 '<div id=\"bodyContent\">'+
                 '<p><b>Fare to Station = ZMW 10 </b><br><b>Inter Station Fare = ZMW 10 </b><br><b>Fare to Destination = ZMW 20 </b><br/><br><b>Total Fare = ZMW 20 </b><br/><b>Distance to next Stop = <span id=\"distanceID\"></span></b></p>'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '</div>';

                 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: contentString,
                 maxWidth: 400
                 });

                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: start,
                  map: map,
            zIndex: google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1,
                  title: '".$originVal."'
                  });
         
                 marker.addListener('click',function(){infowindow.open(map, marker);});
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
        
        
           //InfoWindow at intermediate station
           //infoWindows begin here
              var contentStringStation = '<div id=\"content\">'+
                 '<div id=\"siteNotice\">'+
                 '</div>'+'<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\">'+'Change bus here...'+'</h4>'+
                 '<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\" style=\"color:red;\">Kalomo</h4>'+
                 '<div id=\"bodyContent\">'+
                 '<p><b>Fare to next station = ZMW 10 </b></p>'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '</div>';

                 var infowindowStation = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: contentStringStation,
                 maxWidth: 200
                 });

                 var markerBusStation = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: stophere,
                 map: map,
           zIndex: google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1,
                 title: '".$staWayptName."'
                 });
      
                  markerBusStation.addListener('click',function(){infowindowStation.open(map, markerBusStation);});
        
            
         //InfoWindow at intermediate station 2
           //infoWindows begin here
              var contentStringStation2 = '<div id=\"content\">'+
                 '<div id=\"siteNotice\">'+
                 '</div>'+'<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\">'+'Change bus here...'+'</h4>'+
                 '<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\" style=\"color:red;\">Zimba</h4>'+
                 '<div id=\"bodyContent\">'+
                 '<p><b>Fare to Destination = ZMW 20 </b></p>'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '</div>';

                 var infowindowStation2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: contentStringStation2,
                 maxWidth: 200
                 });

                 var markerBusStation2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: stophere2,
                 map: map,
           zIndex: google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1,
                 title: '".$WayPts2_Name."'
                 });
      
                  markerBusStation2.addListener('click',function(){infowindowStation2.open(map, markerBusStation2);});
         
         
        
            //InfoWindow at final destination
            //infoWindows begin here
               var contentStringDest = '<div id=\"content\">'+
                 '<div id=\"siteNotice\">'+
                 '</div>'+'<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\">'+'your Final stop'+'</h4>'+
                 '<h4 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\" style=\"color:red;\">Livingstone</h4>'+
                 '<div id=\"bodyContent\">'+
                 '<p></p>'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '</div>';

                 var infowindowDest = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: contentStringDest,
                 maxWidth: 200
                 });

                 var markerDest = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: end,
                 map: map,
           zIndex: google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1,
                 title: '".$destName."'
                 });
              
           markerDest.addListener('click',function(){infowindowDest.open(map, markerDest);});
              
         
                 }

                 function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) 
              {
      
                 directionsService.route({
                 origin: start,
                 destination: end,
                 waypoints: waypts,
                 optimizeWaypoints: true,
                 travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        
           }, 
        
           function(response, status) 
            {
              
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
           {
                      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                      var route = response.routes[0];
                      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
                      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
          var distanceSpan = document.getElementById('distanceID');
                      // For each route, display summary information.
                     for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) 
               {
                          var routeSegment = i + 1;
                          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
                          '</b><br>';
                          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
                          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
           summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text + '<br>';

                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
           if(i==0)
           distanceSpan.innerHTML = route.legs[i].distance.text;
                        }
          
          
                    } 
        else 
        {
                      window.location = \"internetError.php\";
                    }
                     });
                  }
       
             
           //center control for map
       
              function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {

                 // Set CSS for the control border.
                 var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
                 controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
                 controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
                 controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
                 controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
                 controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                 controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
                 controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
                 controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
                 controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

                 // Set CSS for the control interior.
                  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
                  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
                  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'calibri';
                  controlText.style.fontSize = '12pt';
                  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
                  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
                  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
                  controlText.innerHTML = 'Show Start Point';
                  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

                 // Setup the click event center map to start location
                 controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
                 map.setCenter(start);
                 });

                 }
    </script>









     
    <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 93%;
      
      z-index:1;
          }
       
          /* Optional: Makes the  page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
       
       /* This only works with JavaScript, 
             if it's not present, don't show loader */
             .no-js #loader { display: none;  }
             .js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
             .se-pre-con {
               position: fixed;
               left: 0px;
               top: 0px;
               width: 100%;
               height: 100%;
               z-index: 9999;
               background: url(images/loader-64x/Preloader_2.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
                }
      
       
        </style>
<html>
    <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
      
      <div style="height: 7%; background-color:#0d70bb;" align="center">
         <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">
      <button style="width: 40%; text-align: center; font-family: calibri; font-weight: lighter; height: relative; background-color: white; border: solid 1px #000000; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 1em; padding: 4px;">Show more Details
      </button></a> 
         <a href="android_home.php">
      <button style="width: 40%; text-align: center; font-family: calibri; font-weight: lighter; height: relative; background-color: white; border: solid 1px #000000; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 1em; padding: 4px;">Try different route</button></a>
      </div>
      
      <div id="toggleText" style="display: none; float:top; z-index: 100000;">
       <div id='directions_panel'
             style='float:top; height: relative; font-family: calibri; text-align:left; padding:5px; background-color:#0d70bb; color: #FFFFFF;
             z-index: 10; font-size: 0.8em;'>
       
       <br/>
       
      </div>
     </div>
       
     <div id='map'> 
         
     
     </div>
    <script async defer
      src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBwiqodRbtEX-U-b3vXlwahF1QlOMw1fug&callback=initMap'>
    </script>
</html>
```